# Find page in memory for Process (linux-kernel)

Tags: c, memory, linux-kernel, operating-system

Basically I have a program that can find all the VMA's of a process, but I would like to look at the pages in the page table for that process as well. I'm stumped. I know that the task_struct for the process has a field

```
pgd_t                  *pgd;                /* page global directory */
```

Is that just an array of indexes to ALL of the pages?

I found this function inside of "/mm/memory.c"

```
/*
* Do a quick page-table lookup for a single page.
*/
struct page *follow_page(struct vm_area_struct *vma, unsigned long address,
                    unsigned int flags)
```

I can pass it a VMA, but I am unsure about what the address and flags should be. Or perhaps this isn't what I want? Any advice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you want to do a rudimentary page walk.

Given a `pgd`, you can iterate through the entries looking for valid `pud`'s, then iterate through the `pud`'s and so on.

One way to do this is using the following:

```
// iterate through your address space
for (i = 0; i < PAGE_SIZE / sizeof(*pud); i++) {
    pud = pud_offset(pgd, PUD_SIZE * i);
    // Check if the pud is valid
    if (pud_none(*pud) || pud_bad(*pud))
        continue;
    // And so on
}
```

Comment: So is the pgd for everything on the system? Or just the process from the task_struct in which it was found? And just to make sure that I understand multilevel page tables, the page that actually has the information (ie. the flags) is in pmd?

Comment: The `pgd` is the root of the page table.  I'm not sure about the current state, but usually the kernel was mapped into the top 1GB of memory in every process.

Comment: Trying to understand your example. Doesn't `pud_offset` expect a virtual address (where you pass `PUD_SIZE * i`)?

Comment: The goal is to iterate through all of virtual memory so it's just making up virtual addresses.  The check afterward is to make sure you don't follow a bad pointer.